# Function returns string and changes encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, character-encoding

My database table looks like:

```
ID    | Name          | Name_Plain
1     | Łódź          |
```

What I want to achieve is, whenever there's insert or update into this table, I want SQL to automatically convert "Name" into text without Polish special characters and write it into "Name_Plan". So the result in the example above should be "Lodz".

I created a trigger and am now trying to code a user defined function which does the conversion from input text to output text.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[usunogonki] (@t nvarchar(50))  RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    return @t
END;
```

The problem is.. the function above almost returns me the text I wanted!  It returns "Lódz". I know it is something with the encoding, because Ł was converted into L and ó stays the same. What I would like from this function is to do exactly what I want, so for now it should return me unchanged text.

I tried some tricks with COLLATE procedure like

```
return (@t COLLATE sql_polish_cp1250_ci_as)
```

but with no success.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Name] NVARCHAR(12)
   ,Name_PLain AS CAST([Name] AS VARCHAR(12)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI 
);


INSERT INTO #TEST ([Name])
VALUES (N'Łódź')

SELECT *
FROM #TEST
```

[image]

creating a computed column which you can materialized if you want. Or basically, to stick with your example:

```
return (@t COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI)
```

Comment: Thanks! what does the job is using VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR. :) Many thanks!